# Does AVAudioEngine support recursive routing?

Tags: audio, core-audio, avaudioengine, augraph

Can I route Node A into Node B, and Node B back into Node A (of course using a Mixer in between) -- otherwise called "Feedback"? (For example, WebAudio supports this).

Answer (score 0):

No, trying to setup a recursive route will result in AVAudioEngine freezing and a seemingly unrelated error appearing in the console:

```
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
```